# UICollectionView loaded from Storyboard is NOT resizing correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm using a UICollectionView created with storyboard, I have applied constraints { .left = 0  .top = 0 .bottom = 0 .right = 0 } to it and expecting it can layout by viewcontroller.view's width and height.

But in viewDidLoad I found that it's width and height equal to the default value specified in the size inspector panel instead of the real screen size.

Now, I need to layout collection view cell by the real size. In `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` if I return the screen size, it will throw a warning

> the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item height must be less that the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

Is there any way to get the correct size of it? Or what is the right way to layout it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the height if an individual cell to be bigger than the height of the collection view itself.
The error message is pretty straightforward.

Can you provide some context as to why you need a cell to cover the whole screen?